# 404 Works only with showing extesion in url bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
.htaccess file:
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

When open website and type in URL example.com/random.php my 404 error work. But when remove extension .php i get error `File not found`. How to solve this problem? I need to automatically respond if there is an extension or not.

I try with `ErrorDocument 404 /404` still not work.

Problem example:

```
example.com/sghiodhg
```

Above example not working, write to me File not found.

Working example:

```
example.com/sghiodhg.php
```

I need to show an error with or without extension

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: What do i need to debug here? I need to create good and working .htaccess code @NicoHaase

Comment: Sounds good, then go for it. If something is not working, then you should provide your attempts to get it working

Comment: I have 3 pages on the folder. What should I go for debug? I even don't have any PHP code just simple pages. @NicoHaase

Comment: Next time, read carefully question because I write my attempts and my attempts stay in question written! @NicoHaase

Comment: I am not sure if it actually makes a difference, but usually `RewriteEngine On` gets placed on top. Even if it should not be technically necessary, I’d do it at least for logical consistency … turn engine on first, _then_ do stuff that is provided _by_ that engine.

Comment: It's the same error. I really don't know how to resolve this error. I want to ask if I can't resolve the error using .htaccess file, can I use PHP code instead of the page not exist redirect to an error page. @CBroe